# OS X Server - Networked home directories become locked after a time

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, osx-server, home-directory, afp

In our infrastructure, we are running OS X 10.8 clients, with networked home directories. The homedirs are served from OS X Server 10.8 via AFP.

Every so often (I haven't figured out the exact timeframe yet), the folders just inside the home directory become locked.

To be more specific, by "locked" I mean that the `uchg` flag becomes set on the folder. The folders I mean are the default OS X home directory folders, Documents, Downloads, Desktop, Movies, Music, and Pictures. The home directory folder itself does NOT become locked, only the folders just under the homedir, and only the ones I listed.

This is happening to very many users, causing all sorts of login and saving issues. The user is allowed to change the flag back by using Get Info on the folders, and unchecking the Locked checkbox. However, it keeps happening, and is happening to way too many users to just tell them how to fix it.

I developed a bash script that runs on the server which searches through home directories and fixes them, but it's only a temporary measure. The issue keeps coming back. By "fixes them", I mean it locates a folder with the `uchg` flag set, and uses `chflags` to unset it.

Has anyone else seen something remotely like this? Are we doing something wrong?